# Why my game is rejected by Crazy Games?

Tags: unity, game-design, html5

I crated this game:
https://muhomorgames.itch.io/bean-legacy
I uploaded it on crazy games I hane no idea why it's been rejected can anyone help me?

Comment: The controls are totally off (tried with mouse, no idea if there are others), the screen is cluttered, the goal is not really clear, no tutorial or options. But what exactly is the reason for rejection, only crazy game can tell.